# Jasper list element inside table element with XML datasource

Tags: list, nested, jasper-reports, xmltable, xmldatasource

I'm trying to generate a report, using *Jasper iReport Designer 5.6.0*, with table that contains lists inside its cells. The generated table could look like this:

[image: Table with nested List]

To do this, I'm using the following XML file as datasource:

```
<report>
<table>
    <persons>
        <person>
            <id>111</id>
            <name>John</name>
            <addresses>
                <address>Johan's Street 1</address>
                <address>Johan's Street 2</address>
                <address>Johan's Street 3</address>
            </addresses>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>222</id>
            <name>Marko</name>
            <addresses>
                <address>Marko's Street 1</address>
                <address>Marko's Street 2</address>
            </addresses>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>333</id>
            <name>Tito</name>
            <addresses>
                <address>Tito's Street 1</address>
                <address>Tito's Street 2</address>
                <address>Tito's Street 3</address>
                <address>Tito's Street 4</address>
            </addresses>
        </person>
    </persons>
</table>
</report>
```

And JRXML template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TableWithList" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="2347c131-1884-430a-b77f-59f08f896c8a">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<subDataset name="PersonsTable" uuid="1470ca7f-50f9-4781-9af7-ed3e04841738">
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/report/table/persons/person]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="person" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[child::text()]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
<subDataset name="AddressesList" uuid="5c62f1af-dfc1-49ca-8615-493009f964f6">
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/report/table/persons/person/addresses]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[address]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/report]]>
</queryString>
<detail>
    <band height="175" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement key="table" x="0" y="0" width="308" height="50" uuid="d3ef2b70-5a74-4ebf-85f5-36fbcac91938"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="PersonsTable" uuid="41f6ef78-fb40-4d6f-9998-e31689321fc8">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/report/table/persons/person")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="122" uuid="3bbeb837-7663-4af6-b2f4-759be2c88102">
                    <jr:columnHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="122" height="30" uuid="3bc07e10-17f3-45ea-8df9-69a3968dc689"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[NAMES]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="33" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="122" height="33" uuid="9d26eb70-a1bc-443c-8fd1-25bcefc6dd58"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="185" uuid="1f779e6e-316b-4442-8e36-c020b7b50d6b">
                    <jr:columnHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="185" height="30" uuid="59998a31-67a7-4ebe-bd15-6f6d3ec38231"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[ADDRESSES]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="33" rowSpan="1">
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="185" height="33" uuid="e6ed252e-e104-489d-bf10-b3ffb0f3ad0e"/>
                            <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                <datasetRun subDataset="AddressesList" uuid="03bc1640-16e7-4111-b48a-0b77e01baefa">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/report/table/persons/person/addresses")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="33" width="185">
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="185" height="33" uuid="eb98e95f-d395-4404-a77b-1660f1de9fd0"/>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

And this is what I'm getting as resulting report:

[image]

Is it possible to have a list element inside the table element? If yes, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are close

Your `<subDataset name="PersonsTable">` is **correct**!

Your `<subDataset name="AddressesList">` should be

```
<subDataset name="AddressesList" uuid="5c62f1af-dfc1-49ca-8615-493009f964f6">
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/report/table/persons/person/addresses/address]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[child::text()]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
```

You need to arrive to node `address`

Since your person table already works we need only to fix the `dataSourceExpression` for the `<jr:list>`

```
<datasetRun subDataset="AddressesList" uuid="c8e1bd7e-b4d8-4e48-8b06-e8fd59846d69">
  <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/person/addresses/address")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

**Thats it**

[image: Result]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this :) I was troubled with this problem for a few days. I was not able to find any example or tutorial explaining how to use lists inside the table. Than you for your quick and precise answer.