# How to use a JRMapCollectionDataSource with Fields and Lists?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to create a report which populates a table of data. I have all the data within a collection of this structure:

```
Collection<Map<String, ?>> dataSource = new ArrayList<>();
```

I create the data as follows:

```
Collection<BatchValue> cashBatches = new ArrayList<BatchValue>();
Collection<BatchValue> checkBatches = new ArrayList<BatchValue>();
Collection<Map<String, ?>> dataSource = new ArrayList<>();    
Map<String, Object> depositMap = new HashMap<>();
depositMap.put("phoneNumber",   deposit.getControllersPhoneNumber());
depositMap.put("accountNumber", deposit.getAccountNumber());
depositMap.put("depositNumber", deposit.getDepositNumber().toString());
depositMap.put("depositDate",   dateFormat.format(deposit.getDepositDate()));
depositMap.put("checkCount", Long.toString(deposit.getTotalPayments()));
depositMap.put("depositAmount", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(deposit.getTotalDepositAmount()));
depositMap.put("cashBatches", cashBatches); //Collection of objects
depositMap.put("checkBatches", checkBatches); //Collection of objects

dataSource.add(depositMap);
```

The object in the collection looks like this:

```
public class BatchValue {

    public BatchValue(String batchNumber, String batchTotal, String checkTotal) {
        super();
        this.batchNumber = batchNumber;
        this.batchTotal = batchTotal;
        this.checkTotal = checkTotal;
    }
    public String batchNumber;
    public String batchTotal;
    public String checkTotal;
    public String getBatchNumber() {
        return batchNumber;
    }
    public String getBatchTotal() {
        return batchTotal;
    }
    public String getCheckTotal() {
        return checkTotal;
    }
}
```

Printing out works except my table data is null.  The report looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2016-01-07T13:29:51 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="cashReceiptsBalanceTape" pageWidth="260" pageHeight="600" columnWidth="220" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c88ca9b5-e46e-4379-a4a6-aa91568a6750">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="rgba(255, 191, 191, 0.0)">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="cashBatches" uuid="d4f4efbb-3bc1-4134-b8a7-4f6fae0756b2">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="batchNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="checkCount" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="batchTotal" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="checkBatches" uuid="b40af45e-8c43-49eb-815a-592bec1f5140">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="batchNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="checkCount" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="batchTotal" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="accountNumber" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="phoneNumber" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="depositNumber" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="depositDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="checkCount" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="depositAmount" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="checkList" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cashBatches" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="9" y="1" width="196" height="16" uuid="7151aef5-2d0d-4982-a07f-602530cd14db">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Deposit Tape]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="9" y="4" width="60" height="16" uuid="2b6a4e34-7d68-4acf-8cd5-fd97ca24e16b"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date Printed]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="M/d/yy h:mm a">
                <reportElement x="69" y="3" width="136" height="16" uuid="2b533300-6aae-428b-a2be-117ea5560848">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="9" y="19" width="100" height="16" uuid="3b875843-da5d-424a-8540-f305c8d2b189">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[State Insurance Fund]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="400" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="69" y="1" width="100" height="16" uuid="3884d87f-bc02-408a-8de8-60bc9869532d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{accountNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="9" y="19" width="100" height="16" uuid="b6c1b69a-4353-4315-99ba-19dd7e75b209">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{phoneNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="113" y="41" width="85" height="16" uuid="070b177a-3384-4886-aac1-1a0fda6e6109">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{depositNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="9" y="41" width="100" height="16" uuid="4e698823-3523-4b98-884e-72541da8e37e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Deposit No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="113" y="57" width="85" height="16" uuid="a3c67e6f-15a1-4f90-ad44-dfca3259a96d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{depositDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="9" y="57" width="100" height="16" uuid="3dacca23-94c7-4f5b-829e-406147029ed0"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Deposit Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="113" y="73" width="85" height="16" uuid="38c09b4e-33ad-48d5-828b-43ccb09d408e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{checkCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="9" y="73" width="100" height="16" uuid="176c17e0-40c0-458e-adb2-5b7df73586a1"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Check Count]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="9" y="89" width="100" height="16" uuid="22f6ee5c-7e7f-4436-b363-7a7611c20a1a"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Deposit Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="113" y="89" width="85" height="16" uuid="111ecf32-09d9-4fc8-99a6-f83fed971e99">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{depositAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="9" y="1" width="60" height="16" uuid="28512e49-36e3-4f4d-970d-97fe1996cb0f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Account No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="16" y="137" width="189" height="103" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="4709e78f-8a76-440c-a660-261c3ece5482">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value="cashBatches"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="cashBatches" uuid="9bd659a0-e16c-47fa-abcf-d0ee807cd1c2">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="d09b02c6-a73e-4020-8198-8a742bfbe7ee">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table 1_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="3ba095fd-0b7c-4e85-b2ad-52c4c0d959f4"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Batch Number]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table 1_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="cb8ca692-b96f-41d5-af5f-b6bbd325166a"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{batchNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="30" uuid="0b05b7df-e05c-45c7-ab76-467eb9679a15">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table 1_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" uuid="de68b063-cc82-4b37-a849-827f9c9d2b59"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Check Count]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table 1_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" uuid="f6756213-69f2-4d88-9d7b-0d7de889a9c5"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{checkCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="102" uuid="6038b058-f354-4322-9c1a-e425c6301ae7">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table 1_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="102" height="30" uuid="f5fc6b01-aa5c-44c3-95f6-da3c1c9c8357"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Batch Total]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table 1_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="102" height="30" uuid="b4a9187e-7b20-49e5-873a-9ee67ae2a555"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{batchTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-11" y="250" width="191" height="150" uuid="93ad77fe-963b-49df-b4c7-abb6891ea914"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cashBatches}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="48" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="95" y="10" width="85" height="16" uuid="a6ca03fc-5921-489a-b9f1-5049e0a7a0e0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{depositAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="84" y="4" width="98" height="1" uuid="3a51cf9c-87c4-4017-8bab-e0e868443242"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

However if I print the field - the data is there as you can see in this image.

[image: Result]

Comment: This may give some additional info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639662/design-ireport-with-tabular-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the issue and I am posting to help others.

One: I needed to use the following to unwrap my class:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource
        ($F{cashBatches})
```

Then I needed to ensure that both the field name and field description were set to the property name or I got an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property ''
```